# How do I place a graphical marker (box, circle, ...) in a MatrixPlot?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to locate minima / maxima in matrices on a heat map. So I have my 2D matrix and did a `MatrixPlot`,

[image: my matrix plot]

and I can find the position of the smallest value.

My question: how do I place a graphical marker at that position? Like a box to outline field (7,6)?

Completely stumped.

Comment: Use the `Epilog` option.

Comment: Thanks, Szabolcs! Works just as expected!

http://imgur.com/uArxaPM

Comment: `Overlay` could work too, but may be more  difficult to position. Another possibility is to use `Show`

Comment: If you want an unfilled `Rectangle`, use `{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], Rectangle[...]}`.

Comment: Okay, 'Overlay' did work as well, though with more overhead. The unfilled box Szabolcs suggested is actually what I was fiddling with just now: [link](http://imgur.com/V0t46gM) - thank you, good sirs!

Answer (score 17):

To position the highlight rectangle properly, the array position of the highlighted value must be converted into a graphics coordinate. For a data array of $n$ rows, to highlight the value at row $i$ and column $j$ requires the bottom left corner of the rectangle to be placed at graphics coordinate $\{j-1, n-i\}$

Example:

```
highlight[data_, patt_, directives_] :=
 {FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[directives],
  Rectangle[{#2 - 1, Length[data] - #1}] & @@@ Position[data, patt]}

data = N@Table[x^2 + y^2, {x, -4, 3, 6/11}, {y, -4, 3, 6/11}];

MatrixPlot[data, Epilog -> {
   highlight[data, Min[data], {Thick, Red}],
   highlight[data, x_ /; 5 < x < 6, {Blue, Dashed}]
   }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an addition to Simon's excellent answer. For large matrices, `MatrixPlot` applies some automatic down-sampling which messes up the coordinates.

Small matrix:

```
m1 = SparseArray[{i_, i_} -> 1, {100, 100}];
mp1 = MatrixPlot@m1;
marker1 = Rectangle[{0, 60}, {40, 100}];
style = Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Dashed], #}] &;

Show[mp1, style@marker1]
```

[image: Small matrix]

Large matrix:

```
m2 = SparseArray[{i_, i_} -> 1, {1000, 1000}];
mp2 = MatrixPlot@m2;
marker2 = Rectangle[{0, 600}, {400, 1000}];

Show[mp2, style@marker2]
```

[image: Large matrix with wrong scale]

One can extract the scale from the second argument of the plot's `Raster` and correct the marker coordinates accordingly:

```
scaleToRaster[coords_, dims_, plot_] := coords * plot[[1, 2, 2]] / Reverse@dims;

Show[mp2, style[scaleToRaster[#, Dimensions@m2, mp2]& /@ marker2]]
```

[image: Large matrix correct scale]